# Flexslider youtube video not playing in firefox

Tags: firefox, video, youtube, flexslider

been working on this all morning but I can't seem to figure this issue out... essentially I have a flexslider that loads images and youtube videos, which works great and loads the youtube video fine in chrome / safari / ie.  However, the videos are not playing at all in firefox and I have no idea why...

I've tried bringing just the video slides with a z-index of 100000, but it still doesn't play the videos at all in firefox at all when they're in the slider

Does anyone have any ideas off hand on how I can get these to work in firefox?  I can provide source code if necessary... sorry if this question is kind of vague. Please let me know if there is anything I can do to clarify. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there some error's in browser console? It would help if you post link for the site.

Comment: nope, no errors in browser console.  I ended up having to basically just use another framework for it to get it so that the videos play in firefox.